# Null check operator used on a null value (fetching profileImage)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I can display profile image but every time home_screen dart reloads i get this error.
i tried without null check but then my code doesn't work.

Error

```
Null check operator used on a null value
```

My code in home_screen.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/user_model.dart';
import 'edit_profile.dart';
import 'splash_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  UserModel? logginUserModel;

  getUserData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      logginUserModel = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => SplashScreen()),
                    (route) => false);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => EditProfile()));
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 125.0,
          width: 125.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(62.5),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              image: NetworkImage(
                logginUserModel!.profileImage == null
                    ? "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Profile_avatar_placeholder_large.png"
                    : logginUserModel!.profileImage!,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error trace of the code

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, state: _HomeScreenState#772d2):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
HomeScreen
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _HomeScreenState.build
#1      StatefulElement.build
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild
#4      Element.rebuild
#5      ComponentElement._firstBuild
#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild
#7      ComponentElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
#31     Element.inflateWidget
#32     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
#33     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (175 frames)
#208    Element.inflateWidget
#209    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
#210    Element.updateChild
#211    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
#212    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
#213    Element.updateChild
#214    ComponentElement.performRebuild
#215    StatefulElement.performRebuild
#216    Element.rebuild
#217    StatefulElement.update
#218    Element.updateChild
#219    ComponentElement.performRebuild
#220    Element.rebuild
#221    ProxyElement.update
#222    Element.updateChild
#223    ComponentElement.performRebuild
#224    Element.rebuild
#225    ProxyElement.update
#226    _InheritedNotifierElement.update
#227    Element.updateChild
#228    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#229    Element.updateChild
#230    ComponentElement.performRebuild
#231    StatefulElement.performRebuild
#232    Element.rebuild
#233    StatefulElement.update
#234    Element.updateChild
#235    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#236    Element.updateChild
#237    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#238    Element.updateChild
#239    ComponentElement.performRebuild
#240    Element.rebuild
#241    ProxyElement.update
#242    Element.updateChild
#243    ComponentElement.performRebuild
#244    StatefulElement.performRebuild
#245    Element.rebuild
#246    BuildOwner.buildScope
#247    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#248    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#249    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#250    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#251    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#255    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#256    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#257    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 6 of 927 libraries in 352ms.
```

Comment: The value you are fetching seems to be NULL

Comment: Can you try with `logginUserModel?.profileImage`

Comment: The issue is here while you are using `!` saying it won't never be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in this line.

```
logginUserModel!.profileImage == null
```

Change it to `loggingUserModel?.profileImage == null`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove `setState(() {})` from `getUserData()` function and try again?
I think you could also use `FutureBuilder` to get your image safely